# How to override OnShareTargetActivated in Template10

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I have a project that needs to receive data from Share-UI Windows 10. I have read documentation from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data) and from that doc it says needs to override OnShareTargetActivated. my question is how to override OnShareTargetActivated in Template10?. so far what I can learn are only this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to override `OnShareTargetActivated` in Template10. In the `Template10.Common.BootStrapper` class, we can see the `OnShareTargetActivated`  that is a sealed method. We can not override the `OnShareTargetActivated`.

In Template 10, the `OnStartAsync` is the one and only entry point to an application. In the `OnStartAsync` method, we can use the `IActivatedEventArgs.Kind` to get the ActivationKind. If it is activation by ShareSource, it will return `ShareTarget`. Then we can convert `IActivatedEventArgs` to `ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs`.

There is a sample for [ShareTarget](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/ShareTarget) in Template10, please refer it.